# How to delete duplicate rows by group?

Tags: r, rstudio, vectorization

How to delete duplicate rows by group with the option to choose how many duplicate rows to keep?

**eg:** Please check Example Picture, for every continuous 1 in `V1`, delete the rows where the `Volume` is duplicated, for `df[2:5,]` row 5 will be deleted, for `df[9:10,]` row 9 will be deleted, `df[15:17,]` row 15,16 will be deleted, `df[19:20,]` row 19 will be deleted.

Also, is it possible to choose how many duplicate rows to keep? eg: if I want to keep 2 duplicate rows, the result for `df[15:17,]` will be `df[15:16,]` where only row 17 got deleted.

How to achieve this without using loops, how do I achieve this the vectorized way so calculation speed is faster(when dealing with millions of rows)?

**Example Picture**

```
    Volume Weight V1 V2 
 1: 0.5367 0.5367  0  1
 2: 0.8645 0.8508  1  0
 3: 0.8573 0.8585  1  0
 4: 1.1457 1.1413  1  0
 5: 0.8573 0.8568  1  0
 6: 0.5694 0.5633  0  1
 7: 1.2368 1.2343  1  0
 8: 0.9662 0.9593  0  1
 9: 1.4850 1.3412  1  0
10: 1.4850 1.3995  1  0
11: 1.1132 1.1069  0  1
12: 1.4535 1.3923  1  0
13: 1.0437 1.0344  0  1
14: 1.1475 1.1447  0  1
15: 1.1859 1.1748  1  0
16: 1.1859 1.1735  1  0
17: 1.1859 1.1731  1  0
18: 1.1557 1.1552  0  1
19: 1.1749 1.1731  1  0
20: 1.1749 1.1552  1  0
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
    Volume Weight V1 V2 
 1: 0.5367 0.5367  0  1
 2: 0.8645 0.8508  1  0
 3: 0.8573 0.8585  1  0
 4: 1.1457 1.1413  1  0
 6: 0.5694 0.5633  0  1
 7: 1.2368 1.2343  1  0
 8: 0.9662 0.9593  0  1
10: 1.4850 1.3995  1  0
11: 1.1132 1.1069  0  1
12: 1.4535 1.3923  1  0
13: 1.0437 1.0344  0  1
14: 1.1475 1.1447  0  1
17: 1.1859 1.1731  1  0
18: 1.1557 1.1552  0  1
20: 1.1749 1.1552  1  0
```

Comment: I think your output should have row 9 instead of 10 as you had taken row 3 instead of row 5

Comment: @akrun I use loops and the code choose a random rows to keep so everytime the result is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `duplicated`

```
setDT(df1)[df1[, (!duplicated(Volume) & V1==1)|V1==0, rleid(V1)]$V1]
```

---

If we need to delete from the duplicate from the reverse direction

```
setDT(df1)[df1[, (!duplicated(Volume, fromLast = TRUE) & V1==1)|V1==0, rleid(V1)]$V1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw, Is it possible to choose how many duplicate rows to keep?

Comment: @Jimmy It could be possible, but it is not clear about the logic

Comment: eg: if I want to keep 2 duplicate rows for every group of continuous `1` in `V1`, the result for `df[15:17,]` will be `df[15:16,]` where only row 17 got deleted. And for `df[2:5,]` no rows will be deleted since there are already two duplicate rows.

Comment: @Jimmy Sorry, I got busy with other stuff.  Perhaps `i1 <-  df1[, head(.I[((duplicated(Volume)|duplicated(Volume, fromLast = TRUE)) & V1==1)], 2), rleid(V1)]$V1;
 i2 <- df1[, .I[V1==0]];
df1[sort(c(i1, i2))]`

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for the reply. If I want to keep 3 duplicated rows instead of 2, do I do this =>  `i1 <- df1[, head(.I[((duplicated(Volume)|duplicated(Volume, fromLast = TRUE)) & V1==1)], 3), rleid(V1)]$V1; i2 <- df1[, .I[V1==0]]; df1[sort(c(i1, i2))]`